# Grid of divs with sliding div beneath each row

Tags: jquery, css-position, jquery-masonry

I need to have a grid of div that are 3 across, which I can do. The part I don't know how to do is, when you click on one of the divs a div slides down beneath that row with detail information. The div that slides down is absolutely positioned all the way to the div on the left so it is 100% width, under all 3 divs. And it is absolutely positioned under each row.

Does that make sense? Should I use Masonry and something else?

Looking for examples or ideas on how to do it.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you floating the grid divs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't heave to use div's with `position: absolute`. I've made a jsFiddle of an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/H9va6/3/

Is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes. I guess the trick will be how I retrieve these rows using an api call to my cms. But that is exactly what I needed to do. I even when in added a second row and it worked as expected. Thanks for the example!

Comment: I was thinking that in order to activate the div by clicking on an element inside the div that I would just add that element to the click  function. I tried that and it did not work, div_column a. Is that right?

Comment: That's possible, but you should refer to the parent div (with the `id`-attribute). Update: http://jsfiddle.net/H9va6/9/.